# Numerical methods for the computation of a square matrix determinant

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, determinant, computer-science, computational-complexity

I have found many different ways to compute the determinant of a square matrix we'll call A over the internet : using LU decomposition, using Cholesky decomposition on the dot product $transp(A) . A$, and LAPACK seems to uses a strange method combining Schur decomposition, Householder's method and scale operations.

As far as I understand, computing the determinant is not a simple task and many approches are available. I believe here would be a good place to list the most common ones, as well as their pros/cons and the different implementation tips and tricks that makes them viable.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no routine in LAPACK for computing determinant. I am not aware of a single *practical* problem where the determinant is the key to the solution. In contrast, the singular value decomposition is very useful. Your question would be greatly enhanced by adding at least one application where computing the determinant is central. Computing the Cholesky decomposition $LL^T = A^TA$ is not a good approach. Compute the $QR$ decomsition of $A$ instead. You will find that $L = R^T$.

Comment: I decided to look for applications which rely on determinants. I can find very few papers and [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00453-001-0032-8) is one of them. The author V.Y. Pan has written several on the subject.